Flutter User Trusted Credentials aren't trusted on Android
I am trying to connect to an endpoint using self-signed CA that I've imported to Android's User Trusted Credentials.
Unfortunately I can't connect to such endpoint until I load cert from the Dart context using: setTrustedCertificatesBytes.
If I need to manage installed certificates from the Flutter app itself, then does it mean Dart VM / Flutter can't make use of native Android's User Trusted Credentials functionality?
final rootCAString = '''-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDazCCAlOgAwI...<certContentsHere>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----''';

class AcceptTrustedCertsHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {

    SecurityContext trustedRootsContext = SecurityContext(withTrustedRoots: true);

    // If I specifically run: `setTrustedCertificatesBytes`, any connection to HTTPS endpoint using cert signed by this rootCA will work OK.
    // final certBytes = Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(rootCAString));
    // trustedRootsContext.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(certBytes);

    final client = super.createHttpClient(trustedRootsContext);

    return client;
  }
}

Call from main.dart
HttpOverrides.global = AcceptTrustedCertsHttpOverrides();

Additionally network_security_config.xml called from AndroidManifest.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system"/>
            <certificates src="user" />  <!-- ADDED THIS SPECIFICALLY -->
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>

Surprisingly on Ubuntu, if I place rootCA.crt in /usr/local/share/ca-certificates location, then Flutter app automatically recognizes it and consider such CA trusted (as expected).
Is it possible for Flutter to automatically load User Trusted Certificates managed by the Android or self-signed certs needs to be managed from the app?

One solution that might work is switching to the Cronet http stack, which is what Chrome uses to do networking:
https://pub.dev/packages/cronet_http
As far as I understand the documentation, this http stack should honor proxies and user-installed certificates!
